# Can an iterator be turned into a pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, iterator

In "13.7.3 async()" of "A Tour of C++" (first print), the following is provided as an example:

```
double comp4(vector<double>& v)
{
  if (v.size() < 10000)
    return accum(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0);

  auto v0 = &v[0];
  auto sz = v.size();

  auto f0 = async(accum, v0, v0 + sz/4, 0.0);
  auto f1 = async(accum, v0 + sz/4, v0 + sz/2, 0.0);
  auto f2 = async(accum, v0 + sz/2, v0 + sz*3/4, 0.0);
  auto f3 = async(accum, v0 + sz*3/4, v0 + sz, 0.0);

  return f0.get() + f1.get() + f2.get() + f3.get();
}
```

where `accum` is defined as follows:

```
double accum(double* beg, double* end, double init)
{
  return accumulate(beg, end, init);
}
```

`vector`, `async` and `accumulate` are the standard library versions.

Running this produces the following error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<double>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >}’ to ‘double*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘double accum(double*, double*, double)’
     return accum(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0);
```

I can get this to work if I use `return accum(&v[0], &v[0] + v.size(), 0.0);` instead. Have I done something wrong in the original formulation?
 Should `vector<double>::iterator` be able to convert to `double*` or is this a mistake with the book? This issue doesn't seem to be mentioned in the errata for both the first and second printings of the book.

Comment: Why would you need an iterator?  The pointer is an iterator in itself, there is no added benefit to using and iterator as it has the same restrictions as a pointer.

Comment: It definitely seems there's a mistake in the book. Pointers can be *used* as iterators, and iterators in a way *emulates* pointers. But iterators aren't inherently pointers (but an iterator can be implemented as a pointer). However, I fail to see why one would use the custom `accum` function instead of calling `std::accumulate` directly.

Comment: auto p = &*I; // what's the fuss about?

Comment: I think there's a bug in the book. (Bjarne's errata are a bit erratic.)

Answer (score 3):

The way `std::vector` is specified, it's entirely possible to implement it by having `vector<T>::iterator` be a typedef of `T*`.

Odds are that whoever wrote that code happened to have a version of `vector` that is implemented that way and got lucky.

Your workaround is the correct way to do this, assuming that the definition of `accum()` doesn't change.

In my opinion, `accum` should have been declared like so:

```
template<typename T, typename ITE>
T accum(ITE beg, ITE end, T init);
```

But then that's essentially `std::accumulate`, so it'd be just redundant.

Comment: This is true for `std::vector<T>`, but not for `std::vector<bool>` because this is not a contiguous iterator. I know it is a rare case and its use is discouraged, but since this is a beginners question I just wanted to add it.

Comment: @Jens: Correct implementation might use `bool*` as iterator (with no specialization for example). standard remove some restrictions on this class to be more space efficiency and so common implementations return a wrapper.